# Dropdownlistfor Selected Value not binding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

The user has already chosen the product, version, and module in this edit form. The product and version work together flawlessly, but I need to shows user selected one. The Selected attribute has been added. The selected attribute also has a value, but it is not obligatory. Please assist in binding the chosen characteristic.

Please see my code below what is wrong with me.

```
UserProducts = bankinfo.FHASMstBankProducts.SelectMany(prod => _productlist.Where(v => v.Id == new ID(prod.txtProductId)),
                                  (n, a) => new Product
                                  {
                                      Id = a.Id,
                                      Name = a.Name,
                                      ProductTitle = a.ProductTitle,
                                      ProductItem = a.ProductItem,
                                      Version = a.Version.Select(v => new ProductVersion
                                      {
                                          Id = v.Id,
                                          Name = v.Name,
                                          VersionItem = v.VersionItem,
                                          ModuleList = v.ModuleList,
                                          Selected = (new ID(n.txtVersionId.ToString()) == v.Id ? true : false)
                                      })
                                  }).ToList()
         }
```

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BankEditViewModel.UserProducts)
 {
     <div class="col-md-3"> </div>
     <div class="col-md-9 p-0 d-flex mt-2 axdf" id="product-section_1">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BankEditViewModel.ProductMaps[1].ProductMapping, new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem { Value = item.Id.ToString(), Text = item.ProductTitle, Disabled = true, Selected = true } }, new { @class = "form-control ml-3 product", @id = "product", @data_index = "", @disabled = "disabled" })
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BankEditViewModel.ProductMaps[1].ProductVersion, new SelectList(item.Version.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Name, Selected = x.Selected }), "Value", "Text", "Selected"), "please select", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "produserversion", @data_index = "", @required = "required" })
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BankEditViewModel.ProductMaps[1].ProductModule, new SelectList(item.Version.SelectMany(m => m.ModuleList).Where(y => y.TemplateId == TemplateIds.ProductModule).Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.Id.ToString(), Text = s.Name }), "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "productmodule", @required = "required" })
         <span id="product-plus"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
     </div>

 }
```

Expected Result :
[image: Screenshot]